# Select from two tables without primary key but same three column field in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

My two tables has no primary key but have same three column field.I select from two tables and come out result like following:

Table1:

```
No    Code    Row    Price
001   0001    1      100
001   0001    2      200
002   0001    1      300
```

Table2:

```
No    Code    Row    Qty    Date
001   0001    1      10     2016
001   0001    2      20     2017
```

Result Table:

```
No    Code    Row    Price    Qty    Date    Row2
001   0001    1      100      10     2016    1
001   0001    1      100      10     2016    2
001   0001    2      200      20     2017    1
001   0001    2      200      20     2017    2
```

My SQL:

```
Select 
T2.No,T2.Code,T2.Row,T1.Price,T2.Qty,T2.Date,T1.Row as Row2
From Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2
On T1.No = T2.No
And T1.Code = T2.Code
Order by T2.Code,T1.Row
```

I want result to come out like this:

```
No    Code    Row    Price    Qty    Date    Row2
001   0001    1      100      10     2016    1
001   0001    2      200      20     2017    2
```

What should I write SQL? Please advice me.. I'm new to SQL.
If I modify query like this:

```
Select 
T2.No,T2.Code,T2.Row,T1.Price,T2.Qty,T2.Date,T1.Row as Row2
From Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2
On T1.No = T2.No
And T1.Code = T2.Code
And T1.Row = T2.Row
Order by T2.Code,T1.Row
```

It comes out nothing...
Please help me.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you using MYSQL or SQL Server? It can't be both.

Comment: You could try commenting out each of the conditions separately. It's possible that the values aren't actually an exact match, but only appear to match.

Comment: I don't know what's going on but your modified query [works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e72fc/2) given your sample data. Are you trying to match NULLs? Are the data types of `T1.Row` and `T2.Row` compatible?

Comment: I used SI Object Browser.

Comment: Oh my God! T1.Row is CHAR data type and T2.Row is VARCHAR2 data type. What should I do? Actually, T2 is dummy table.

Comment: @Ic  I really thank u. It fine now, I changed the data type of row field when create table. Thank u so much.

Comment: Since you are new to SQL, let me point out that your Primary key does not need to always be a single unique 1-up integer. A "Primary key" just needs to uniquely identify a row and you can have a compound primary key (which you appear to have). I'm a SQL SERVER guy, but I'm sure MySQL also allows you to define your key this way, which (1) prevents duplicates and (2) increases performance. At least in SQL SERVER you don't need to have your Primary Key also be your Clustered Index (although it is common to be both).

Comment: When T1.Row and T2.Row data type is not same, it comes out null result.When T1.Code and T2.Code data type is also not same,But it FINE. I don't know how different.After I change the data type of T1.Row and T2.Row, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Left Join will solve your problem.

```
SELECT T2.No,T2.Code,T2.Row,T1.Price,T2.Qty,T2.Date,T1.Row as Row2
FROM Table2 T2 
LEFT JOIN Table1 T1 ON T1.No = T2.No
     And T1.Code = T2.Code
     And T1.Row = T2.Row
ORDER BY T2.Code,T1.Row
```

Comment: Left join didn't work for me. It comes out Table 2 data of all are null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server try this query

```
Select * from 
(
Select *,row_number()over(partition by date order by no) as row2 from
(
Select 
Tbl1.*,tbl2.qty,tbl2.date 
From tbl1 inner join tbl2 on tbl.no=tbl2.no
) as ab
)as bc  where  row2=1
```

I hope this would help you.